# R programming, row-wise data frame calculation with custom script (for every i) to solve "bridge game"

Tags: r, function, dataframe, for-loop, rowwise

I have a data frame which specifies "bridge games" (every row is one independent game), see a minimal example with 4 games below:

```
start <- list(c("10","15","5"), c("5") ,c("11","6"),c("6","11"))
end <- list(c("7","17","11"), c("10"), c("8","12"),c("8","12"))
ascending <- c("+","-","+","-")
position <- c(11,6,9,8)
desired_output <- c(5,5,"disqualified",3)

bridge_game <- data.frame(start = I(start), end = I(end), ascending = ascending, position = position, desired_output = desired_output)

bridge_game
```

**How does the bridge game work?**
Candidates all over the world participate in a bridge game challenge and we have collected the data of every bridge game in a data frame. Every bridge consists of numbered wooden panels (positive integers that not necessarily have to start at 1) and "gaps" of broken panels. The candidate can choose from which side of the bridge he is starting his walk (ascending = the numbering of the panel increases as the walk progresses; or descending = the numbering of the panel decreases as the walk progresses).

A graphic for a better understanding of the bridge game can be found here (exemplified for the 1st row in the data frame):
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LiqJ.png)

For every bridge game (= row in the data frame) we have the following information (= columns):

- bridge_game$**start**: all start positions of tracts of whole wooden
  panels (random order)
- bridge_game$**end**: all end positions of tracts of whole wooden
  panels (random order)
- bridge_game$**ascending**: walk across the bridge in ascending (+) or
  descending (-) order of panels
- bridge_game$**position**: candidate ended up at the indicated panel

**What is the challenge?**
I need to write a script that I can run row-wise over the whole data frame to get the following output:

- bridge_game$**desired_output**: test whether candidate fell down into the river (ended up at a broken panel and is "disqualified"). And if he is not disqualified I need to calculate the **number of whole wooden panels** covered by the candidate's walk (broken panels don't count).

Importantly, it should work for **any number *i* of whole tracts** of wooden panels.

To be more precise I give a step-by-step instruction how the requested R script should operate below:

**0) solved**

a) Convert list of characters into numeric list for columns bridge_game$start and bridge_game$end.

b) Calculate *i* (the number of tracts of whole wooden panels; *i* goes from *1* to *i=max* for every row) and sort the start and end positions to get the correct start and end values for every *i*.

**1)** Test whether the position is at a broken panel:
end(i=1 to max-1) > position > start(i=2 to max) --> if TRUE for any of the tested pairs --> "disqualified"

**2)** If no, test in which tract of whole panels the given position lies (*i = n*): start(i=1 to max) <= position <= end(i=1 to max) --> if TRUE give back i (= n)

**3)**

a) Apply this formula (if direction is ascending "+" and n = 1): *output = position - start(i=1) + 1*

b) Apply this formula (if direction is descending "-" and n = i max): *output = end(i=max) - position + 1*

c)Apply this formula (if direction is ascending "+" and n > 1): *output = position -   start(i=1) + 1 - (start(i=2 to n) - end(i=1 to n-1) - 1x[n-1])*

d) Apply this formula (if direction is descending "-" and n < i max): *output = end(i=max) - position + 1 - (start(i=n+1 to max) - end(i=n to max-1) - 1x[i=max - n])*

I hope I got the math right there. To check for the correct output I have created a "desired_output" column in the "bridge_game" data frame.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your image is sorely lacking in completeness as to the rules.   Please post the full set of rules,  **as text**  , in your question.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your comment. I added more text to better explain the problem. Would you have any ideas how to write this script? Cheers, omit

Comment: Good description!  Now just turn each line into code :-) . I think you're on your way

Comment: Hey, I am stuck with this since days..Would appreciate any hint on how to turn this into code from step 1) on :-)

Comment: @Ben Yes `n` is calculated the same as `regions` in my other question. For row 4 the calculation works using formula 3 d): `output` = 12 - 8 + 1 - (11 - 8 - 1(2-1)) = **3**. I am calculating the difference for every pair of start and end positions, where **i** is ranging from the indicated minimum to maximum value. Importantly, the value **i** is shifted by one for every start/end pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems i have more simple solution for step #3. Function `npanels` creates a vector from the panel numbers, determines the position of the player's stop in it. If the direction of movement is positive (`ascending` variable is `"+"`), then this is the desired solution, if negative, then the desired value is calculated based on the length of this vector.

```
start <- list(c(5,10,15), c(5) ,c(6,11),c(6,11))
end <- list(c(7,11,17), c(10), c(8,12),c(8,12))
position <- c(11,6,9,8)
ascending <- c("+","-","+","-")
game <- data.frame(start = I(start), end = I(end), position = position, ascending = ascending)

npanels <- function (data) {
  v <- unlist(Map(":",
                  unlist(data[["start"]]),
                  unlist(data[["end"]])))
  p <- which(v == data[["position"]])
  l <- length(v)
  b <- 1+l-p
  d <- data[["ascending"]]
  n <- ifelse(d == "+", p, b)
  n <- if(is.na(n)) "disqualified" else n
  return(n)
}

game$solution <- apply(game, 1, npanels)

game
```

Answer (score 4):

You have overcomplicated this problem. Consider the following implementation

```
parse_pos <- function(x) sort(as.integer(x))

construct_bridge <- function(starts, ends) {
  starts <- parse_pos(starts); ends <- parse_pos(ends)
  bridge <- logical(tail(ends, 1L))
  whole_panels <- sequence(ends - starts + 1L, starts)
  bridge[whole_panels] <- TRUE
  bridge
}

count_steps <- function(bridge, direction, stop_pos) {
  if (isFALSE(bridge[[stop_pos]]))
    return("disqualified")
  start_pos = c("+" = 1L, "-" = length(bridge))[[direction]]
  sum(bridge[start_pos:stop_pos])
}

play_games <- function(starts, ends, direction, stop_pos) {
  mapply(function(s, e, d, sp) {
    bridge <- construct_bridge(s, e)
    count_steps(bridge, d, sp)
  }, starts, ends, direction, stop_pos)
}
```

Output

```
> with(bridge_game, play_games(start, end, ascending, position))
[1] "5"            "5"            "disqualified" "3"
```

The key here is that we can use a logical vector to represent a bridge, where a broken/whole panel is indexed by `F`/`T`. Then we just test whether the stop position is on a whole panel or not. Return the sum of panels from the start to end position if so (broken panels will not affect the sum as they are just zeros) or "disqualified" otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

This might provide you with what you need for your third step. I modified the function from your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65049499/test-whether-position-x-is-between-any-start-i-1-to-i-max-and-end-i-1-to-i-ma).

First, would check if `n` (or `region`) is `NA`. If it is, then there was no match for the `position` between `start` and `end`.

Otherwise, you can include 2x2 combinations of `if` `else` looking at `ascending` and `n`. The equations use similar extraction of values from `x`. Of note, it looks like you want to `sum` the values where there is a range of indices (e.g., when you say "start(i=2 to n)" you want to `sum` the values, such as `sum(start[2:n])`).

Note that this translates your equation into code directly as it seemed was desired. However, there are simpler alternatives based on the logic described in the other answers.

```
start <- list(c(5,10,15), c(5) ,c(6,11),c(6,11))
end <- list(c(7,11,17), c(10), c(8,12),c(8,12))
ascending <- c("+","-","+","-")
imax <- c(3,1,2,2)
position <- c(11,6,9,8)

example <- data.frame(start = I(start), end = I(end), ascending = ascending, imax = imax, position = position)

my_fun <- function(x) {
  n <- NA
  out <- NA
  start <- as.numeric(unlist(x[["start"]]))
  end <- as.numeric(unlist(x[["end"]]))
  for (i in 1:x[["imax"]]) {
    if (between(x[["position"]], start[i], end[i])) n <- i
  }
  if (!is.na(n)) {
    if (x[["ascending"]] == "+") {
      if (n == 1) {
        out <- x[["position"]] - start[1] + 1
      } else if (n > 1) {
        out <- x[["position"]] - start[1] + 1 - (sum(start[2:n]) - sum(end[1:(n-1)]) - (n - 1))
      }
    } else if (x[["ascending"]] == "-") {
      if (n == x[["imax"]]) {
        out <- end[x[["imax"]]] - x[["position"]] + 1  
      } else if (n < x[["imax"]]) {
        out <- end[x[["imax"]]] - x[["position"]] + 1 - (sum(start[(n+1):x[["imax"]]]) - sum(end[n:(x[["imax"]] - 1)]) - (x[["imax"]] - n))
      }
    }
  }
  out
}

example$desired_output <- apply(example, 1, my_fun)
```

**Output**

```
      start       end ascending imax position desired_output
1 5, 10, 15 7, 11, 17         +    3       11              5
2         5        10         -    1        6              5
3     6, 11     8, 12         +    2        9             NA
4     6, 11     8, 12         -    2        8              3
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Step 0) is done:

```
#Change to numeric
bridge_game$start <- lapply(bridge_game$start, as.numeric)
bridge_game$end <- lapply(bridge_game$end, as.numeric)

#Calculate number of tracts of whole wooden panels
bridge_game$tracts <- lapply(bridge_game$start, length)

#Sort start and end positions
bridge_game$start <- lapply(bridge_game$start, sort)
bridge_game$end <- lapply(bridge_game$end, sort)

#Calculate number of tracts of whole wooden panels
bridge_game$tracts <- lapply(bridge_game$start, length)
```

Struggling from step 1) on...