# Test whether position x is between any start (i=1 to i=max) and end (i=1 to i=max) positions stored in lists

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vector

I have a simple data frame with specifies start and end positions within lists. These start and end positions define i number of regions. Now I would like to test whether a given position lies within such a region and if yes I need to know in which region (i).

Here is a simple example data frame:

```
start <- list(c(5,10,15), c(5) ,c(6,11),c(6,11))
end <- list(c(7,11,17), c(10), c(8,12),c(8,12))
imax <- c(3,1,2,2)
position <- c(11,6,9,8)

example <- data.frame(start = I(start), end = I(end), imax = imax, position = position)
```

When I have only one start and end position it is no problem (as in row 2 of example):

```
data.table::between(example$position[[1]], example$start[[1]], example$end[[1]])

[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

How can I turn this into a function which checks this pairwise for every element (from i=1 to i=max) within example$start and example$end?

The second step would be to retrieve for which region i (1 to imax) this was TRUE.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might be looking for a function like this.

As your `start` and `end` are lists, you can `unlist`. To check each element pairwise, you can loop through `start` and `end` up to `imax`.

Assuming you can have more than one region, you can return a list (or something else) at the end of the function.

```
my_fun <- function(x) {
  vec <- integer(0)
  start <- unlist(x[["start"]])
  end <- unlist(x[["end"]])
  for (i in 1:x[["imax"]]) {
    if (between(x[["position"]], start[i], end[i])) vec <- c(vec, i)
  }
  list(vec)
}

example$regions <- apply(example, 1, my_fun)
```

**Output**

```
      start       end imax position regions
1 5, 10, 15 7, 11, 17    3       11       2
2         5        10    1        6       1
3     6, 11     8, 12    2        9        
4     6, 11     8, 12    2        8       1
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for this! It works! The above problem is actually part of a bigger problem. The ultimate goal would be to solve this "bridge game" here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65003498/r-programming-row-wise-data-frame-calculation-with-custom-script-for-every-i?noredirect=1#comment114985914_65003498
Basically, only step 3) would be missing after your input now. Do you know how to program these functions in 3) a), b), c), d)?
I am stuck with this "bridge game" since days.. -.-
Cheers